# How to schedule a Template to run multiple times a day in ansible tower?

Tags: scheduling, cron-task, ansible-template, ansible-tower

[There is no option to add multiple times a day..it's limited to just once a day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y07kD.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the template to run the multiple times a day by setting the **Repeat Frequency** in **Hours** instead of **Days**.

[image]
And Under **Frequency Details** Section, set the duration between Job to Job per day.
[image]

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.5.0/html/userguide/scheduling.html

Thank you.